# mex file not executing in MATLAB 7.5.0 (R2007b)

Tags: matlab, mex, matlab-coder

I created a **`.mex`** file of a MATLAB file `test.m` from MATLAB R2012b using MATLAB coder.

I got the output file `test_mex.mexa64`. I was hoping to use this `.mex` file in MATLAB 7.5.0 (R2007b) but it shows the following error.

```
Invalid MEX-file '/work/sreekanthl/test_mex.mexa64': libmwblascompat32.so: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

How can I make this `.mex` file work in 7.5.0 (R2007b)?

Comment: Upgrade.  Seriously.  Upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

While TMW says that mex functions are usually compatible between versions, it's [not officially supported](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103048-are-mex-files-and-p-code-forward-and-backwards-compatible-across-matlab-versions) and quite [common](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/326009) to run into issues with it.

The only reliable option is to simply recompile the generated source code that Matlab coder created (i.e., the C code) in the version you want to run it in using the `mex` function.

Comment: To my experience, especially running mex compiled with recent versions of Matlab in old Matlab versions causes problems.

Comment: The 2014b release seems to be a big breakpoint. Compiling with 2013b usually works well for several releases beforehand, but I'm always running into problems if I compile with >2014b.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [David Kelley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32315130/3297440) for general MEX files but there is a special consideration for MATLAB Coder generated MEX files. MATLAB Coder generated MEX code is expected to be forward compatible but generally is not expected to be backward compatible. In other words, you are expected to be able to use such MEX code in a newer release than the one with which it was generated, however using the code in an earlier release cannot be guaranteed to work.

The reason for this is that the MEX code uses various runtime libraries which ship with MATLAB. These libraries advance over time and the MEX file from the newer version may depend on features that the older libraries do not provide, or even on a new library which does not exist in the older release as you are seeing here.

If you want to create MEX code that is compatible with earlier releases, you could generate a standalone target such as a static library or a shared library (LIB or DLL respectively for MATLAB Coder), and either:

1. Try to use `loadlibrary` to call the generated code in MATLAB
2. Write a generic MEX interface for it and compile that MEX code in the older release

These options are more work but should enable you to create a MEX file or shared library usable in an older release.